# Polymer 1.0 paper-input in firefox

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In Firefox, the `paper-input` doesn't show the caret. In Chrome it does.

Here is the demo page for the `paper-input` tag:

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?view=demo:demo/index.html

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: Ben, Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Have you tried this in your own app at all? I have an app that uses a `paper-input` which shows the caret in firefox. Maybe it's just a bug with the way the docs are setup.

Comment: I have tried it in my app as well. I see the same behavior. I used polymer started kit to set up the project, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been reported in https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/110 and https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/108

Seems to be a bug in 1.0.4 so you can overcome this by sticking to 1.0.3